# Entity Framework Core Find and Update single value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core-2.2

As you can see i am retrieving the record first and then make another call to update it. Is there a way to do all in 1 call with EF?

```
            var registo = _context.Registos.Find(registoId);
            registo.IsArranqueSerieActivo = true;

            _context.Registos.Attach(registo);                

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```